# Split the result of 'counter'

Tags: python, count

I count the occurrences of items in a list using

```
timesCrime = Counter(districts)
```

Which gives me this:

```
Counter({3: 1575, 2: 1462, 6: 1359, 4: 1161, 5: 1159, 1: 868})
```

I want to separate the parts of the list items (3 and 1575 for example) and store them in a list of lists. 
How do I do this?

Comment: You are  basically asking how use .keys and .values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter
In [2]: cnt = Counter({3: 1575, 2: 1462, 6: 1359, 4: 1161, 5: 1159, 1: 868})
In [3]: [cnt.keys(), cnt.values()]
Out[3]: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [868, 1462, 1575, 1161, 1159, 1359]]
```

A benchmark:

```
In [4]: %timeit zip(*cnt.items())
The slowest run took 5.62 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.06 µs per loop

In [5]: %timeit [cnt.keys(), cnt.values()]
The slowest run took 6.85 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 591 ns per loop
```

In case you want the output of `Counter.items` transformed into a list of lists:

```
In [5]: [list(item) for item in cnt.iteritems()]
Out[5]: [[1, 868], [2, 1462], [3, 1575], [4, 1161], [5, 1159], [6, 1359]]
```

Answer (score 8):

`Counter` is a `dict`, so you have the usual `dict` methods available:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counter = Counter({3: 1575, 2: 1462, 6: 1359, 4: 1161, 5: 1159, 1: 868})
>>> counter.items()
[(1, 868), (2, 1462), (3, 1575), (4, 1161), (5, 1159), (6, 1359)]
```

If you wanted them stored column major, just use some `zip` magic:

```
>>> zip(*counter.items())
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), (868, 1462, 1575, 1161, 1159, 1359)]
```